# Is it possible to have several html files within one chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Hello Stack community!

I am currently writing a Chrome web browser extension, and I came across a slight predicament.

I was planning to have several html pages present, to which the user could switch to upon button clicks, certain events triggering and whatnot, however it does not seem possible.

For example, I have a button on the main html page:

```
        <div class="sec-1">
            <button type="button" class="track" id="verif">Verify & Confirm</button>
        </div>
```

& the JS

```
window.onload = document.getElementById("verif").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "verified.html";
};
```

Very simple, but for some reason it does not work. The console does not show me any errors when launched.

After searching around, I came to a conclusion that chrome extensions are single page mini web apps and cannot have more than one html page in view. The solution that I found, was alter the html via JS, which is a valid idea, but it calls for far too much manual labor in my case.

Could anyone suggest an alternative idea, or if it is possible to have several html pages, point me in the right direction?

Honestly I've just been searching google for any alternatives but couldn't find much.

EDIT 1:

So I've come to a somewhat roundabout solution in regards to my question, however I'll still keep it open as someone may point out a simpler way to go about this. I've gone with the earlier method of altering the html via JS, if anyone is interested the main snippet is below:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('verif');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var popupView = chrome.extension.getViews({type: "popup"})[0];
        popupView.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>New content</h1><p>This is the new content</p>";
    });
});
```

Comment: Assigning `location.href` in `window.onload` doesn't make sense here. That will redirect the page as soon as it's loaded, and the click handler is redundant.

Comment: Are you trying to assign the click listener during `window.onload`? That should be `window.onload = () => document.getElementById(...).onclick = ...`

Comment: Thank you! I caught that a bit later on, however the problem still persists. At this point I've gone with just replacing the html content manually via JS. Original post has been updated.

Comment: Extensions pages aren't SPA and can be redicted via location.href, so there must be something unusual in the way you do it, which is not obvious from your description, so maybe you can add more info + why are you using getViews, which is redundant within the same context (view). Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.